# new Array ложный массив

Tags: javascript

Задача из codewars "Mexican Wave". Получаем строку(слово), нужно вернуть массив слов, где начиная с первого слова и первой буквы один знак должен быть верхнем регистре и так до последней. Количество слов, соответственно, равно количеству символов в строке. Задача простая, с ходу написал `return` в одну строку.

```
return new Array(str.length).fill(str.split("")).map((el,ind,ar) => {el[ind] = el[ind].toUpperCase(); return el.join("")})
```

Но результат не тот:

```
[
    "Rock",
    "ROck",
    "ROCk",
    "ROCK"
]
```

Перевел это решение в цикл, но и тут тоже самое. Добавил для сравнения обычный массив, результат положительный.
Объясните в чем разница между массивами `с` и `z`

```js
function cycle(b) {

  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i += 1) {

    b[i][i] = b[i][i].toUpperCase()

    b[i] = b[i].join("")

  }

  return b
}

function wave(str) {

  let c =  new Array(str.length).fill(str.split(""))

  let z = [["r","o","c","k"],["r","o","c","k"],["r","o","c","k"],["r","o","c","k"]]
  
  return [cycle(z),cycle(c)]
}

console.log(wave("rock"))
```

Comment: [Похоже, это ответ на ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1547880/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/1547894#1547894) - Если коротко, то вы каждую итерацию модифицируете один и тот же объект

Comment: Кстати, ваше решение работает не правильно, т.к. по условиям задачи, надо игнорировать пробелы и в верхний регист поднимать следующую букву. т.к. для строки ' qwe ' ответом должен быть массив из 3х элементов

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. Массив перевел через JSON. И в конце добавил filter.                                   
 return (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Array(str.length).fill(str.split("")))).map((el,ind,ar) => {el[ind] = el[ind].toUpperCase(); return el.join("")})).filter(x => x.match(/[A-Z]/))

Comment: Можно ответить на свой же вопрос это приветствуется.